# PHP exec() not returning all command output - OS X

Tags: php, macos, unix, terminal

I am using PHP to find out if a piece of hardware is attached to the server. I am using the following php command on a Mac OS X server. But not all results are returned, makes me feel like they are buried in an array I can't get to.

In Terminal I run:

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

The output is:

```
   USB Hi-Speed Bus:

  Host Controller Location: Built-in USB
  Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBEHCI
  PCI Device ID: 0x1e2d 
  PCI Revision ID: 0x0004 
  PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086 
  Bus Number: 0x1a 

    Hub:

      Product ID: 0x0024
      Vendor ID: 0x8087  (Intel Corporation)
      Version:  0.00
      Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
      Location ID: 0x1a100000 / 2
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Current Required (mA): 0

        FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in):

          Product ID: 0x8510
          Vendor ID: 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
          Version: 80.25
          Serial Number: CC2C9C098NDN9KE0
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Location ID: 0x1a110000 / 3
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 500
```

when I run the same command in php:

```
  exec ("system_profiler SPUSBDataType");
```

only this is returned:

```
  USB 3.0 SuperSpeed Bus:
  Host Controller Location: Built-in USB
  Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCI
  PCI Device ID: 0x1e31
  PCI Revision ID: 0x0004
  PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086
  Bus Number: 0x0a
```

My full php is as follows:

```
  <?php
  $usbDevices = array();
  exec ("system_profiler SPUSBDataType", $usbDevices);
  foreach ($usbDevices as &$value) {
  echo $value .'<br />'; 
  }
  ?>
```

Print_r doesn't help, I've searched around and couldn't find too much to help with. Any ideas. Thanks

Update 1

It's not an Array issue, it's simply that _www doesn't seem to be able to capture this data. Even when I pipe the output to a file I get the same result. Using `exec()` I get a very limited result, but when I run the same command in the terminal I get full results.

Any thoughts on allowing www user to access this extra data?

Comment: are you sure all of that's going to stdout? exec won't return stderr output by default.

Comment: @Dagon same thing, still doesn't work :(

Comment: random shot: `var_dump(passthru("system_profiler SPUSBDataType'));`

Comment: @Dagon nope var_dump(passthru("system_profiler SPUSBDataType")); 
returns exactly the same but with an additional null

Comment: ugly option pipe to file, read file `passthru("system_profiler SPUSBDataType >file.txt');` assume that will work for mac ?

Comment: @Dagon Yeah, the system_profiler command actually has the ability to export to a XML file which I could also do. I would love to figure  it out this way though. But at least I have a back up plan

Comment: it looks like the output of the server function is such that php thinks its finished (perhaps the null is a clue) and so returned. if this is the case not much you can do to get around it.

Comment: @MarcB yup it's printed to stout

Comment: @Dagon I thought that too but much more is printed afterwards which I removed to save space. exec() prints 4 items, all hubs. when I run system_profiler SPUSBDataType on the command line it prints all the devices in-between each hub as if they are nested arrays. I'll attach the XML file so it's clearer.

Comment: seems unlikely(?) but would a different user get a different result?

Comment: @Dagon i added the system_profiler command to sudoers and still no change. I figure that _www may not have permissions to see that level of information. I'll sleep on it... maybe it will hit me in the morning. thanks for your help